# Web API "Nested" Route?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

No real code here, but looking for direction.  I am using .net core web api.  A potential requirement came up to use somewhat of a nested route for the api that is based on the user.

ie:  https://blah.com/controller/YourNameHere/variable

Is that even possible?

I am used to this format in a controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

I also believe you can specify static route like /api/[controller]/somethingstatic/id for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify routes on the ControllerMethods you use by specifying it with the HttpGet prefix: Eg:

```
[HttpGet("StageResult/{name}/something/{id}")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<TeamResultsDTO>> GetStageResults(string name, int id){ ...
```

It is explained more clearly here: 
[How to pass multiple parameters to a get method in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280947/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-get-method-in-asp-net-core/56089569)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!