# NET Core: Filtering with HttpGet

Tags: .net-core, filtering, http-get

I would like to filter a list of vehicles, by their makeId using httpGet. The URL I would expect to use is:
https://localhost:5001/api/vehicle?makeId=2

Below, I will define the DTO and controller methods I used for this task:

FilterDto

```c#
public class FilterDTO
{
    public int? MakeId { get; set; }
}
```

Below are the 2 HTTPGet methods in my controller class. I expect the first method to be called.

```c#
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<VehicleDTO>> Get(FilterDTO filterDto)
{
    var filter = _mapper.Map<Filter>(filterDto);
    var vehicles = await _vehicleRepository.GetAll(filter);
    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<VehicleDTO>>(vehicles);
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<VehicleDTO>> Get(long id)
{
    var vehicle = await _vehicleRepository.GetWithRelated(id);

    if (vehicle == default)
    {
        return BadRequest("Vehicle not found");
    }

    var result = _mapper.Map<VehicleDTO>(vehicle);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

With the above code, when I call the URL above, in Postman I get a 400 Error, saying "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
I get the same result for https://localhost:5001/api/vehicle

If I change the first Get method like below, I am able to get a response:

```c#
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<VehicleDTO>> Get(int? makeId)
{
    var filter = new Filter { MakeId = makeId};
    var vehicles = await _vehicleRepository.GetAll(filter);
    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<VehicleDTO>>(vehicles);
}
```

After this (lengthy) introduction, my questions are:

- Why does HttpGet support 'int?' but not the data transfer object 'FilterDto'?
- Should I be using a different verb instead of HttpGet?
- I might have to filter in the future for some other types (say customerId). Is there any way I can change the method to support custom objects, like FilterDto, ideally without changing the verb?

Comment: This question might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280947/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-get-method-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @Luuk I would like to pass a single parameter, not 4 (see the old Uncle Bob saying), but in the worst case scenario I'll try this.

Comment: use [FromQuery] attribute and you can use DTO as parameter

Comment: @SinaRiani if you can, please post this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follow:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<VehicleDTO>> Get([FromQuery] FilterDTO filterDto)
{
    var filter = _mapper.Map<Filter>(filterDto);
    var vehicles = await _vehicleRepository.GetAll(filter);
    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<VehicleDTO>>(vehicles);
}
```

and call it like:

```
baseUrl/Controller/Get?MarkId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the  [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Basically the primitive types are supported, but the controller has no idea how to convert your web request data into C# object. You need to explicitly tell it how you want this custom object to be created out of web request.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I believe you may be right. I'll test this in the next hours and come back with the result.
Do you know why this doesn't apply to HttpPut or Post? There I could safely use a method with the signature: 

`[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<VehicleDTO>> Update(long id, SaveVehicleDTO vehicleDTO)`

Answer (score 0):

You may have in mind that HttpGet methods are only able to receive primitiveTypes (string, int, short, datetime -using a specific format-) because the arguments are being sent through query string, for example:

```
myAddres.com/api/mymethod?id=5&filter1=value1&filter2=value2
```

Having this consideration in mind you'll notice there's no way to send any object because you need to use a json or another notation, remember querystring has a limit and because of that is better using "argument=value" notation.

On the other hand PUT and POST are able to send their data through a "body" property where you may use a json notation and this way you may create almost any object on your Backend side.

If you need to use an object as an argument it is a better idea using POST or PUT (better POST than PUT).

Comment: Using [FromQuery], as @SinaRiani said, allows you to use binding parameters. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#binding-source-parameter-inference